# With JSDOC for javascript, how to make a single method in an object have a template parameter

Tags: javascript, generics, types, jsdoc

In Javascript, using JSDoc, how can a single method in a @typedef be documented to have a generic/templated parameter?

```
---- typedef.d.js ----
/**
 * @typedef MyService {
 *  @property {() => string[]} otherFunc
 *  @template ArrayT
 *  @property {(a: ArrayT[]) => ArrayT[]} shuffleArray
 * }
 */
```

In the above typedef, `@template ArrayT` does not work. It shows the desired effect that the single shuffleArray method's type is generic, but the rest of MyService is not. In other words, shuffleArray should be able to take any array type without having to instantiate a new MyService object for that type.

```
---- MyService.js ----
/** @typedef {import('my-app').MyService} MyService */

export const MyService = /** @extends {MyService} */ (
  class {
    /** @returns {string[]}
    otherFunc() {
      return ['I', 'am', 'not', 'generic'];
    }

    /**
     * @template ArrayT
     * @param {ArrayT[]} a
     * @returns {ArrayT[]}
     */
    shuffleArray(a) {
      return shuffle(a);
    }
  }
);
```

The `@template ArrayT` above does work, but its typing isn't relayed to the rest of the app, because the rest of the app uses the MyService typedef from typedef.d.js.

```
---- someOtherFile.js ----
import MyService from './MyService.js';
const myService = new MyService();
const a1 = myService.shuffleArray([1, 2, 3, 4]);
const a2 = myService.shuffleArray(['1', '2', '3', '4']);
```

The hope is to use the same instantiated service to generically accept different types of arrays without having to make the whole MyService generic and to not have to use a type of `any`.